# How to pass id of the clicked HTML row in javascript to another javascript

Tags: javascript

code used so far:

```
var showStores = function (userArray) {

        userArray.forEach(function (dat) {

            $('.store')
                    .append('<div id="idstores" name="idstores" value="5" type="hidden"></div>\
                    <div class="store-img" id="storeImg" value ="5"><img src="' + dat.storeImageUrl + '" /></div>\
                <div class="store-text2"><h3>'+ dat.pointsNeeded + ' Hero Points<br>\
                ' + dat.prize + ' at ' + dat.storeName + '</h3></div></div>').click(function () {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("idstores", dat.idstores);
                });  
        })        
    };
```

As of now on click all the value of idstore from 1..9 is displayed .

Comment: Why does your div have a name and value and type attribute? I think that should be an input.

Comment: Pass to what?  Another JavaScript, PHP, an unnamed wide receiver?

Comment: Pass to another javascript

Comment: `.append` inside a forEach  is a performance killer, specially when handling a large number of elements. Consider concatenating HTML String and than appending only once after the concatenation loop.

Answer (score 0):

So... You want to create elements on the fly and within the creation make them clickable and store it into `sessionStorage`:

```js
var SSitems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.idstores) || {},
    all$items = []; // Store all created $() items

function create$item( item ){
  var $item = $("<div/>", {
    // (P.S: DIV cannot have TYPE nor NAME properties)
    id    : "store_"+ item.idstores,
    class : "store",
    html  : `<div class='store-img'>
              <img src='${item.storeImageUrl}'>
            </div>
            <div class='store-text2'>
              <h3>${item.pointsNeeded} Hero Points etc...</h3>
            </div>`,
    on    : {
      click : function(){
          SSitems[item.idstores] = item;
          sessionStorage.idstores = JSON.stringify(SSitems);
          console.dir( JSON.parse(sessionStorage.idstores) );
      }
    }
  });
  // Now that the div is created and click handler is assigned
  all$items.push( $item );
}

function showStores(userArray) {
  userArray.forEach(create$item);       // Loop / create elements
  $('#storeItems').append( all$items ); // Append only once!
};

// TEST
var data = [
  {idstores:0,  storeImageUrl:"http://placehold.it/50x50", pointsNeeded:30},
  {idstores:23, storeImageUrl:"http://placehold.it/50x50", pointsNeeded:130}
];
showStores(data);
```

Here's a [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/woceto/7/edit?html,css,js,console,output) since StackOverflow's sessionStorage is sandboxed by it's iframe... :(

Answer (score 0):

This code and idea was taken from `jeff_mcmahan`'s answer which he later deleted after caving under the pressure of scrutiny and having some coding oversights.  The major thing I added to his code was to create a function that made a user and then cast it into an array variable that can be accessed by a `for loop`.

Below is a snippet of the code that is doing most of the work.

```
for (c = 0, y = users.length; c < y; c++) {
  var storeName = users[c][0];
  var storeImage = users[c][1];
  var pointsNeeded = users[c][2];
  var prize = users[c][3];
  var storeString = '<div class="idstore-' + c + ' hiddenDiv" data-name="idstores" data-value="5">' +
    '<div class="store-img" data-id="storeImg" data-value="5">' + '<img src="' + storeImage + '" />' + '</div>' +
    '<div class="store-text2">' +
    '<h3>' + pointsNeeded + ' Hero Points<br/>' + prize + ' at ' + storeName + '</h3>' + '</div></div>';
  storeArray += storeString;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ezne7yLc/20/)

```js
var users = [];
storeArray = '';

makeUser("Target", "http://images.clipartlogo.com/files/images/36/361352/ancient-city-under-full-moon_p.jpg", 550, "Bible + Strong's Concordance");
//Source:Ancient City Under Full Moon from clipartlogo.com (by Bazaardesigns)
makeUser("Wal-Mart", "http://images.clipartlogo.com/files/images/39/396186/abstract-city-illustration_p.jpg", 250, "Interlinear Bible + Predestination");
//Source:Abstract City Illustration from clipartlogo.com

function makeUser(storeName, storeImageUrl, pointsNeeded, prize) {
  var user = [];
  user.push(storeName);
  user.push(storeImageUrl);
  user.push(pointsNeeded);
  user.push(prize);
  users.push(user);
}

for (c = 0, y = users.length; c < y; c++) {
  var storeName = users[c][0];
  var storeImage = users[c][1];
  var pointsNeeded = users[c][2];
  var prize = users[c][3];
  var storeString = '<div class="idstore-' + c + ' hiddenDiv" data-name="idstores" data-value="5">' +
    '<div class="store-img" data-id="storeImg" data-value="5">' + '<img src="' + storeImage + '" />' + '</div>' +
    '<div class="store-text2">' +
    '<h3>' + pointsNeeded + ' Hero Points<br/>' + prize + ' at ' + storeName + '</h3>' + '</div></div>';
  storeArray += storeString;
}

$('#masterDatabase').append(storeArray);

$('div.hiddenDiv').on("click", function() {
  // Access the clicked element with evt.target or 'this' keyword
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
div.hiddenDiv {
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 290px;
}
div.hiddenDiv h3 {
  font-size: .75em;
  color: blue;
  font-family: arial;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
.store-img {
  max-height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.selected {
  background-color: #ACE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='masterDatabase'>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to give each `<div>` you're appending a unique id. Hopefully, there's a unique key in each `userArray` element you can use for this. Secondly, provide a `class` for the outer `div`. (This will be the same for all.)

Inside the jQuery `click()` handler, you can access the properties of the clicked element via the `this` keyword. To get the `id` of the element, use `this.id`. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with this id, so I'll give a generic example.

```
element.click(function () {
   alert(this.id);
}
```

This simply displays an alert with the `id`, but you can do whatever you want with it, such as putting it somewhere in session storage as it looks like you're attempting.

**UPDATE**

Here's a revised version of your code. First let's append your `<divs>` with unique id's and a class. Here, I'm assuming that `aUniqueIdentifier` is a unique property of each `userArray` element. I'm also giving all the outer divs a `class` named `myClass`.

```
userArray.forEach(function (dat) {
    // I'm leaving out some of the HTML you're appending for brevity
    $('.store').append('div id="' + dat.aUniqueIdentifier + '" class="myClass">...</div>')
}
// Now that all your elements are appended, we add a click handler to all elements that have class myClass
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    // Click handler
    sessionStorage.setItem("idstores", this.id);
}
```

Comment: Using this.id , returns empty string. Also, there is another problem, there are 9 stores which I am displaying on screen. I want to get information of the store that I click on and pass store-id to next page. However, when I click on any store, all the 9 objects are getting passed.

Comment: See updated answer. For getting the id, you can also try `this.attr('id')`

Comment: If you're going to downvote, I'd appreciate feedback